# Flexible repository architecture for multiple ORMs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, repository, data-access-layer

I started my project with Dapper as our ORM because we wanted to get up and running nice and quickly and simply. I'm now at the stage where we want to upgrade so we aren't writing loads of SQL in code with joins etc. I've decided that I want to use Entity Framework (I don't really want to discuss whether you should or shouldn't be using repositories with EF). However, I don't have time to just refactor all my repositories in one go. I am using interfaces but so far the interfaces have been fairly specific to each POCO object, with methods such as `GetFoo`, `UpdateFoo`, `GetFooByBarId` etc which is not great. I want to genericise the CRUD operations into common method names (Select, Upsert, Delete).

This presents me with the first problem which is if I change the names of the repository methods then I have to go and change all the references in all the projects and deploy all the applications which doesn't sound too fun or safe to me. I want the transition to be gradual.

I also want to retain the ability to use Dapper or any other ORM in future if I want to without restricting myself to EF forever.

I've started to create EF repositories now and my project structure is something like this:

- Core (POCO models and other common code).
- DAL (Repository interfaces)
- DAL.Dapper (Dapper implementations of repositories)
- DAL.EntityFramework (EF implementations of repositories)
- Various projects/applications that use a mixture of repo implementations

I have already created a base repository in my base DAL project that looks like this:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<T> Get(object id);
    Task<IQueryable<T>> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, params RepositoryFlags[] flags);
    Task<IQueryable<T>> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, Expression<Func<T, T>> fields, params RepositoryFlags[] flags);
    Task<int> Upsert(T item);
    Task Delete(T item);
}
```

The problem with this is that the GetMany methods are applicable for EF but not really for Dapper (converting an expression to SQL is not something I really want to get into). I want to be able to use these methods for EF repositories only. I've spent a while deliberating how to do this and subsequently haven't fully committed to the new EF implementations yet because I don't want to force myself to implement methods in Dapper repositories that I don't need.

I've just thought of a new idea which I think will give me the ability to share common methods via the DAL base interface but also allow me to have extra ORM-specific functionality when I want it and have it all work with Dependency Injection.

**DAL project**

IBaseRepository

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    Task<T> Get(object id);
    Task<int> Upsert(T item);
    Task Delete(T item);
}
```

IExtendedBaseRepository

```
public interface IExtendedBaseRepository<TModel, TExtensions> : IBaseRepository<TModel>
    where TModel : class
    where TExtensions : class
{
    TExtensions Extensions { get; set; }
}
```

**DAL.Dapper project**

FooRepository

```
public class FooRepository : IBaseRepository<Foo>
{
    // CRUD implementations...
    // ...
}
```

**DAL.EntityFramework project**

FooExtensions

```
public class SupplementRepositoryExtensions
{
    private readonly TapContext context;

    public SupplementRepositoryExtensions(TapContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAll()
    {
        ...
    }

    public Task<IQueryable<Foo>> GetMany(Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> where)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

FooRepository

```
public class FooRepository : EFBaseRepository<Foo>, IExtendedBaseRepository<Foo, FooExtensions>
{
    public FooExtensions Extensions { get; set; }

    public FooRepository(DbContext context, FooExtensions extensions) : base(context)
    {
        this.Extensions = extensions;
    }
}
```

(EFBaseRepository contains EF CRUD implementations)

**DI in application 1**

```
services.AddTransient<IBaseRepository<Foo>, DAL.Dapper.Repostories.FooRepository>();
```

**DI in application 2**

```
services.AddTransient<FooExtensions>();
services.AddTransient<IExtendedBaseRepository<Foo, DAL.EntityFramework.RepositoryExtensions.FooExtensions>, DAL.EntityFramework.Repositories.FooRepository>();
```

**Usage in application 2**

```
public class FooService
{
    private readonly IExtendedBaseRepository<Foo, FooExtensions> fooRepository;

    public FooService(IExtendedBaseRepository<Foo, FooExtensions> fooRepository)
    {
        this.fooRepository = fooRepository;
    }

    public async Task Bar()
    {
        var foos = await this.fooRepository.Extensions.GetAll();

        ...
    }
}
```

I believe this gives me the flexibility I want while maintaining a degree of commonality between ORMs. I'm just looking for opinions on this architecture really. Is it any good? Am I overlooking any obvious issues or is this a horrible anti-pattern or something? Open to suggestions or improvements.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really an answer, but I decided to file one since it exceeded the character limit of a comment by far.

To be honest, I think Dappers and EFs level of abstracting queries are too different to abstract them further via a common layer in a way that doesn't influence (and complicate) your application logic too much. Our overall application architecture is quite similar to yours (Core <= Data <= (Data.Impl1, Data.Impl2,...)), and we also thought about supporting different capability levels of OR-Mappers. End of story was, that we agreed upon only supporting OR-Mappers that are built on top of `IQueryable<T>` to keep it maintainable. So our Repository/UoW-abstraction roughly looks like:

```cs
public interface IDataSet<T> : IQueryable<T>
    where T : class, new()
{
    T AddOrUpdate(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity);
    void Commit();
}

public class EntityFrameworkDataSet<T> : IDataSet<T>
    where T : class, new()
{
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _underlyingSet;

    public EntityFrameworkDataSet(DbContext ctx)
    {
        _underlyingSet = ctx.Set<T>();
    }

    //Implement IDataSet<T> 
    //Implement IQueryable<T> redirecting to IDbSet<T>
}
```

We simply don't support Dapper-like frameworks and purely rely on LINQ to query data.

> Am I overlooking any obvious issues

I guess you already came around that fact, but: Every OR-Mapper brings his own set of restrictions to your domain model - mostly M:N or Primary/Foreign-Key stuff. Supporting multiple OR-Mappers therefore means bringing *multiple* restriction-sets to your domain model. You have to decide whether you can still map your requirements to a reasonable (and still object oriented) domain model within those boundaries.

Comment: Thanks @Peter! Totally understandable approach and I think I'd have done the same if I hadn't started out with Dapper in the first place! This may become my long-term goal to work towards though as I phase out Dapper.

Answer (score 2):

The chief issue is that you're working at two different levels. Dapper is a so-called "micro-ORM", but at the end of the day you're still dealing with a lot of straight SQL, so it actually benefits from something like the repository pattern. Entity Framework, however, does not. The only way you can successfully handle both via a repository layer is to discard much of the functionality EF buys you, basically going least common denominator with Dapper. This boils down to a core deficiency in the repository pattern as a solution to your particular problem. I know you said you didn't want to talk about that, but this is life, and we don't always get what we want. The truth of the matter is that this is the wrong approach.

Instead, you should look into alternative abstraction patterns such as CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation), the service layer pattern, or microservices. The unifying feature of all three of these patterns is that they completely abstract away the database work from your application. Each set of data or each operation that you need to perform on some data is neatly tucked away into a specific command/query, service method, or API call. The actual database work then, can be done however you please and can be easily changed at a whim without affecting your application at all. You can use Dapper for one thing, EF for another, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks @chris. I guess I was just trying to avoid too much rewriting but I may not have a choice! I do actually use the service layer pattern in places but it takes repositories as dependencies. How would I go about changing this to work with both Dapper and EF whilst remaining ORM-agnostic? Or should the service in fact NOT be ORM-agnostic and for example, take an EF DbContext as a dependency?